# java.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation not found

Tags: xmpp, jks

In my application i am using xmpp and openfir for chat. Chat is working fine but in log i am getting below exception. I googled it I couldn't find an answer. Where should i implement jks

```
05-25 12:59:27.245 25643-26419/com.it.example D/SMACK: 12:59:27 PM SENT (161744330): <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
```

05-25 12:59:27.365 25643-26419/com.it.example D/SMACK: 12:59:27 PM RCV  (161744330): 
05-25 12:59:27.365 25643-26419/com.it.example W/System.err: java.security.KeyStoreException: **java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation not found**
05-25 12:59:27.375 25643-26419/com.it.example W/System.err:     at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:119)
05-25 12:59:27.375 25643-26419/com.it.example W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.ServerTrustManager.(ServerTrustManager.java:71)
05-25 12:59:27.375 25643-26419/com.it.example W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:858)
05-25 12:59:27.375 25643-26419/com.it.example W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:250)
05-25 12:59:27.375 25643-26419/com.it.example W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:46)
05-25 12:59:27.375 25643-26419/com.it.example W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:72)
05-25 12:59:27.375 25643-26419/com.it.example W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore jks implementation not found
05-25 12:59:27.375 25643-26419/com.it.example W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:190)
05-25 12:59:27.375 25643-26419/com.it.example W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:139)
05-25 12:59:27.375 25643-26419/com.it.example W/System.err:     at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:116)
05-25 12:59:27.375 25643-26419/com.it.example W/System.err:     ... 5 more

Comment: Which Smack version is this?

Comment: asmack-android-19-0.8.10